# Extracting Data from manifest.xsf file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I trying to extract information about the rules that are applied to a number of InfoPath forms, and I am using Powershell to do so.

I have unpacked the `template.xsn` file, and found the `manifest.xsf` file that stores this data.

Using the Powershell `[xml]$ProjectXmlFile = Get-Content manifest.xsf` to get the xml data, I am struggling to identify the nodes correctly.

The nodes are identified using the "`xsf:`" precursor, for example:

```
<xsf:submit caption="Submit" disableMenuItem="no" onAfterSubmit="close" showStatusDialog="no">
    <xsf:errorMessage>The form cannot be submitted because of an error.</xsf:errorMessage>
    <xsf:davAdapter name="SharePoint Library Submit" submitAllowed="yes" overwriteAllowed="no">
        <xsf:folderURL value="../"></xsf:folderURL>
        <xsf:fileName value="my:Submit/my:ref" valueType="expression"></xsf:fileName>
    </xsf:davAdapter>
</xsf:submit>
```

How do I identify these nodes in order to get the information out as normal xml data (i.e. if the nodes didn't have "xsf:" prefixing them)?

This is what I've been trying to use:

```
foreach ($DataQuery in $ProjectXmlFile.'xsf:xDocumentClass'.'xsf:dataObjects'.'xsf:dataObject'.'xsf:query'.'xsf:sharepointListAdapterRW')
 {
        Write-Host "DataQuery.name = $($DataQuery.'xsf:name')"
}
```

Or is there another reason that I can't access these nodes?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the [`XmlTextReader.Namespaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader.namespaces?view=netframework-4.8) property to the `$false` value, you can disable namespace support.

```
$x = @'
<xsf:submit caption="Submit" disableMenuItem="no" onAfterSubmit="close" showStatusDialog="no">
    <xsf:errorMessage>The form cannot be submitted because of an error.</xsf:errorMessage>
    <xsf:davAdapter name="SharePoint Library Submit" submitAllowed="yes" overwriteAllowed="no">
        <xsf:folderURL value="../"></xsf:folderURL>
        <xsf:fileName value="my:Submit/my:ref" valueType="expression"></xsf:fileName>
    </xsf:davAdapter>
</xsf:submit>
'@
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$sr = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StringReader $x
$xtr = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlTextReader $sr
$xtr.Namespaces = $false
$xml.Load($xtr)
$xml.'xsf:submit'.'xsf:errorMessage'
```

**Output:**

```
The form cannot be submitted because of an error.
```